# What is the closest equivalent in Objective-C for "data.response.venues[0].name" when trying to get a specific value from a JSON response?

Tags: objective-c

I have a json string from the Foursquare venues API (see below).  It's in the form of an NSData object from the following code:

```
NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
```

I'd like to retreive the name of the first venue in the json.  I find myself wanting to type "data.response.venues[0].name".  Does Objective C have something similar to this one-line syntax for grabbing a specific value from an NSData object?

JSON

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "response": {
        "venues": [{
            "id": "503de4dce4b0857b003af5f7",
            "name": "monkeyHut",
            "contact": {},
            "location": {
                "lat": 40.7,
                "lng": -74.0,
                "distance": 0,
                "postalCode": "10004",
                "cc": "US",
                "city": "New York",
                "state": "NY",
                "country": "United States",
                "formattedAddress": ["New York, NY 10004", "United States"]
            },
            "categories": [{
                "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1e1931735",
                "name": "Arcade",
                "pluralName": "Arcades",
                "shortName": "Arcade",
                "icon": {
                    "prefix": "https:\/\/ss1.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/arts_entertainment\/arcade_",
                    "suffix": ".png"
                },
                "primary": true
            }],
            "verified": false,
            "stats": {
                "checkinsCount": 24,
                "usersCount": 16,
                "tipCount": 4
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to parse the JSON response data in the `NSData` object to actual Cocoa dictionary/array objects (available from iOS 5.0):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"Invalid response");
    return;
}
```

You can then use `objectForKey:`/`objectAtIndex:` or their literal variants as shown below to access the data:

```
NSString *name = object[@"response"][@"venues"][0][@"name"];
```

**DO NOT** use this code directly, because a JSON response with another layout than you expect (e.g. `data.response` is changed from a dictionary to an array) will cause a runtime error when trying to use an object as a dictionary, when it actually is an object of another type. You can check the type of your objects using the following:

```
if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

}
```